# foreach my $var ($var, $var) expression in Perl

Tags: perl, loops

How to interpret expression `foreach my $nm ($a, "default")`? AFAIK, by `my $nm` we replace standart `$_` special character for current variable access within current loop, but I can't understand relations between loop args. `$a` is also string, if it has meaning, and let's suppose, that `$a = "foo"`.
How can it be used excepting getting `$nm = "foodefault"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you crating the `()`, it means you are creating the `list`.

Then you have itreating loop for those list elements.

For example

```
my @ar = ($a,"default");

foreach (@ar)
{
```

In above code you are creating the list and storing into the array. And iterating for these `@ar`

> > How can it be used excepting getting $nm = "foodefault"`?

For this question, you can use the `join` function

```
my $nm;

foreach  ($a,"default")
{
    $nm.=$_;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*foreach* means exactly what it says.

The first time around the loop, the value of `$nm` will be the same as the value of `$a`.

The second time around the loop, the value of `$nm` will be the same as the value of `"default"`.

Comment: Thank you for reply! Could you share to me the link to docs describing such behavior of this loop?

Comment: I was here of course. Unfotunatelty, this moment rather unobvious as well as whole Perl :)